# When you buy WoW, do you still have to pay for more features?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I like the game, and I am hoping that if I buy the game I get the game and won't keep having to pay money for it or for extra features.

Answer (score 8):

WoW has a monthly fee. You will have to continue paying the monthly fee if you want to continue playing. However it does have a free to play option with added limitations, this is called the [Starter Edition](https://us.battle.net/account/creation/wow/signup/).

**EDIT**

You mentioned in your other question that you have some kind of a limited internet access. Keep in mind that the Starter edition would be a very large download. Additionally, there are occasional updates to the game client that require large downloads. This may mean you would have additional costs associated with playing WoW.

Comment: depending on how you define "large download", that's outdated information - the streaming client is a much, much smaller download than the full client used to be.  In any case, you can always get the game on disc.  The updates being large downloads is also somewhat outdated, since the Cataclysm launcher now allows you to start playing after a relatively small amount has been downloaded.

Comment: It allows you start playing, but continues to download in the background, meaning you still need to download many gigs of content.  Last time I did a clean install from the Cataclysm disc I still had to download over 2GBs of patches.  My parents have a 1GB bandwidth cap per month, so it would very much be considered a large download to them.

Comment: full download is in the order of 16 Gigabytes (starter edition will afaik still play the full client, so have the complete download).

Comment: @Delameko - wow, what ISP limits monthly bandwidth to 1GB in 2012? that's worse than most mobile plans these days...

Comment: A very cheap one ;)  (£2.99 - $4.80ish - a month if I recall)  It got upgraded to 10GB about 6 months ago though, I think thats probably the bottom cap now.

Answer (score 4):

The mandatory costs for World of Warcraft:

- Purchasing of the game itself and associated expansion packs.  This is a one-off.
- Internet access and WoW's monthly fee.  These are periodic fees required to play the game.

You can also optionally spend money on cosmetic items like mounts and pets.

Comment: You don't have to buy the game and its expansion packs at the same time. However, the "Battle Chest" ed. contains both the game, the first expansion pack and 30 days play for a low price.

Comment: the battle chest does not contain all expansions.

Answer (score 1):

When you buy all the sets (the expansions and all the stuff that require for you to play) you just have to pay a fee every month.

To be able to *play* and log into the game, you don't need to pay anything else except the fee **every** month. Also there are other payment plans that cost a bit less than the monthly renewal.